# ADC Samples Extraction

Tags: fpga, adc

I am using an 14 bit ADC-EVM board . After giving some input Analog signal to ADC . I want to extract the I and Q data of the sampled signal. please help me to understand how to do this.

Comment: To extract I and Q information you need a reference signal.

Comment: I have an reference signal (-50 dbm , 250MHz ) . i want to extract I and Q of mentioned reference signal to some .txt file

Comment: You'll need to generate a 90 degree phase shifted version of the reference signal and using both references multiply them with the analogue signal then average and take the square root to obtain I and Q.

Comment: I think you might be confused as what the ADC does and what I and Q are

Comment: and ".txt file" is a concept that is really, really far away from the basic question of how to deal with an ADC.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic IQ demodulator running at 8MHz, your system will be much the same except for the much higher frequencies (you're in a realm where ADCs get really expensive really fast).

An ADC only samples a signal, to separate out the I and Q data, you need to demodulate your signal. You basically need two mixers being driven from a frequency generator locked to your signal of interest. One mixer is fed straight from the frequency generator (almost always a PLL or DDS), this gets you the I or *"In-phase"* channel. The other mixer gets fed a 90' phase shifted signal from your frequency generator, this gets you the Q or *"Quadrature"* channel.

After you've accomplished all this, you're then free to do whatever you need to do with the now successfully *demodulated* IQ data.

[image]